# Can't install Discovery Studio Visualizer

Tags: software-installation, binary

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I ran .bin file through terminal to install DS Visualizer, but i got the following errors:

```
./install_DSClient.sh: 49: ./install_DSClient.sh: [[: not found
./install_DSClient.sh: 70: ./install_DSClient.sh: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an interpreter problem, you'll have to change it to a correct one. In fact, there will be more similar problems along the way. Simply follow [this procedure](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=293074) (listed below), it's very detailed and worked for me on Ubuntu as well. You also might have to install `csh` and `tcsh` at some point.

In the following steps, replace "username" with the name of your home directory. This also assumes that you are installing in a folder for your applications that I have called "progs" (short for "programs").

Before installing DSV, consult the System Requirements on the Biovia webpage, and install as many of the recommended libraries as you can. Because Biovia only supports RHEL, CentOS, and SUSE, you will need to translate the library names from rpm to deb nomenclature.

1. Download biovia_2019.ds2019client.bin to "/home/username/Desktop"
2. `chmod +x biovia_2019.ds2019client.bin`
3. `./biovia_2019.ds2019client.bin --noexec --target /home/username/progs/BIOVIA2019`
4. `cd /home/username/progs/BIOVIA2019`
5. Open "install_DSClient.sh" with text editor
6. Change `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`
7. Insert `shopt -s expand_aliases` above `alias echoe="echo -e"` and save file.
8. Make executable: `chmod +x install_DSClient.sh`
9. Run installer: `./install_DSClient.sh`
10. When prompted to select install location, choose 2, write "home/username/progs/BIOVIA2019", return, choose 1, return, choose 1, return. (Note: after installation, all the extracted files in path under procedure `9` will be deleted. And this specified location will contain whole package files except the `License` files *check below steps*. Besides, this location will be used for the generation of `.desktop` file.)
11. `cd /home/username/progs/BIOVIA2019/DiscoveryStudio2019`
12. `cd lp_installer`
13. `chmod +x lp_setup_linux.sh`
14. `./lp_setup_linux.sh --noexec --target /home/username/progs/BIOVIA2019`
15. `cd /home/username/progs/BIOVIA2019/LicensePack/etc`
16. `./lp_config`
17. Open "lp_echvars" in a text editor
18. change `#!/bin/csh -f` to `#!/bin/tcsh` and save and close file. (Note: `tcsh` is used in this step, install it if your OS doesn't have)
19. `./lp_echovars`
20. `cd /home/username/progs/BIOVIA2019/DiscoveryStudio2019/bin`
21. `./config_lp_location /home/username/progs/BIOVIA2019/LicensePack/`
22. `cd /home/username/progs/BIOVIA2019/DiscoveryStudio/lib`
23. `mv libz.so bk.libz.so` (Note: no worries in this step and below step, if you don't find this shared dynamic library under the path. Actually, it should not have.)
24. `mv libz.so.1 bk.libz.so.1`
25. `cd /home/username/progs/BIOVIA2019/DiscoveryStudio2019/bin`
26. Run the program: `./DiscoveryStudio2019`
27. Optional: open DiscoveryStudio2019 in text editor; change `ACCELRYS_DEBUG=0` to `ACCELRYS_DEBUG=1`. Then when DSV is started via the terminal, you will get a verbose readout that can be inspected for errors.

**Debug**

Follow the very last step, turn on the verbose printing by setting up `ACCELRYS_DEBUG=1`. In terminal, execute `/path/to/your/DiscoveryStudio/executor`, if any error happens, it will be printed out in the end, following those information (most time due to the lack of libraries), do the debugging. Good luck!

Comment: Hi! It's great to credit someone for their work when solving a problem for someone and it would be even more brilliant if also added the details of the procedure to your post just in case someone stumbles on this answer in 5 years and at that point the link is broken :)

Comment: Thanks! Without this, I don't know how long I would've to struggle.

Comment: Note: those procedures still work for DS2021.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet, so here is the working version of the Anna's answer for Ubuntu.

2. `chmod +x BIOVIA_2021.DS2021Client.bin`
3. `./BIOVIA_2021.DS2021Client.bin --noexec --target /home/ubuntu/Software/BIOVIA`
4. `cd /home/ubuntu/Software/BIOVIA`
5. Open "install_DSClient.sh" with text editor
6. Change "`#!/bin/sh`" to "`#!/bin/bash`"
7. Insert "`shopt -s expand_aliases`" (without quotes) above "`alias echoe="echo -e"`" and save file.
8. Make executable: "`chmod +x install_DSClient.sh`"
9. Run installer: "`./install_DSClient.sh`"
10. Choose all 1. It will be installed in the default directory `/home/ubuntu/BIOVIA`. In the end copy all the content from `/home/ubuntu/Software/BIOVIA` to `/home/ubuntu/BIOVIA`. Delete `/home/ubuntu/Software/BIOVIA`.
11. `cd /home/ubuntu/BIOVIA/DiscoveryStudio2021`
12. `cd lp_installer`
13. `chmod +x lp_setup_linux.sh`
14. `./lp_setup_linux.sh --noexec --target /home/ubuntu/BIOVIA`
15. `cd /home/ubuntu/BIOVIA/LicensePack/etc`
16. `./lp_config`
17. Open "lp_echovars" in a text editor
18. change "`#! /bin/csh -f`" to "`#! /bin/tcsh`" and save and close file.
19. `./lp_echovars`
20. `cd /home/ubuntu/BIOVIA/DiscoveryStudio2021/bin`
21. `./config_lp_location /home/ubuntu/BIOVIA/LicensePack/`
22. `cd /home/ubuntu/BIOVIA/DiscoveryStudio2021/bin`

Run the program:
`./DiscoveryStudio2021`