# Installation of Biovia DS visualiser 2021 on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: software-installation, 22.04

I am trying to install Biovia DS visualiser2021 on ubuntu 22.04. I used the procedure from the following website

[Can't install Discovery Studio Visualizer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1175772/cant-install-discovery-studio-visualizer)

When I run the installer `./install_DSClient.sh` I got the following error

```
Uncompressing License Pack and extracting files, please wait.

./install_lp.sh: 73: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

  Copying 1 files to ./share/license/data/tempdata.dat Please wait... Copying 1 files to /home/user/BIOVIA/DiscoveryStudio2021/Logs/dsclientinstall.log Please wait...

Completed installing  DiscoveryStudio2021 at /home/user/BIOVIA/DiscoveryStudio2021

Check log file [ /home/user/BIOVIA/DiscoveryStudio2021/Logs/dsclientinstall.log ] for more information. Return code: 0
```

Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: `Completed installing  DiscoveryStudio2021` suggests that installation might have completed despite the error. Are you sure it needs to be solved?

Comment: An icon has been created but I couldn't launch it.

Comment: Did you check the content of `/home/user/BIOVIA/DiscoveryStudio2021/Logs/dsclientinstall.log` as suggested?

Comment: Also check your syslog and journalctl for messages/warnings/errors about what happened after you tried to launch the application. Those will usually tell you the REAL problem.

Comment: @user535733 .  Problem is with the lpinstaller.  ./lp_setup_linux.sh

Comment: @user535733  ./install_lp.sh: 73: Syntax error: redirection unexpected